# Why too much recursion

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why in this case there is too much recursion. I didn't use any loop.

```
function a(param1, param2) {

    function b(input1) {
        return input1 * 2;
    };

    function c(input2) {
        return input2 * 2;
    };    

    return a(param1) + b(param2);
};

document.write(a(1, 2));
```

Comment: You are calling `a(param1)` inside `a`. Maybe you intended to call `c` instead...

Comment: Where's your stopping condition?  I don't see one.  This recursion will go on forever.

Comment: Are you familiar with recursion at all? Did you try to learn it?

Comment: _Recursion demistified_: It's only recursion, not magic. Recursion is just a function calling another function. No need to learn that (John can do it now). Now, the tricky bit is when to stop. If a function calls itself you need to have a changing parameter/external variable that tells it when to stop.

Answer (score 5):

In `a` your `return` statement is calling `a` again, thus will do so infinitely. You probably meant:

```
return b(param1)+c(param2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Function a keeps calling itself. Did you mean to call function c instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a inside a. That will keep piling the stack with function calls to itself.
You haven't specified any terminating condition for your calls, hence the recursion goes till you run out of memory.